# How to find out supported modes for given cipher in mcrypt?

Tags: php, cryptography, mcrypt

PHP has functions:

- http://cz.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-list-modes.php - it lists all available modes but you can't add algorithm name.
- http://cz.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.constants.php - RC4 is a stream cipher

Can I presume that all other ciphers implemented in mcrypt supports CBC, OFB, NOFB, CFB, and ECB block cipher modes?

In theory they should. I'm interested if it is so in practice.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is quite easily tested :-)

Comment: Yes, I tested it, not systematically though. It seems I will have to do it properly. :) It should definitely be described in the PHP documentation.

Comment: One could argue that the library [introduction page](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php) says this: *This is an interface to the mcrypt library, which supports a wide variety of block algorithms such as DES, TripleDES, Blowfish (default), 3-WAY, SAFER-SK64, SAFER-SK128, TWOFISH, TEA, RC2 and GOST in CBC, OFB, CFB and ECB cipher modes.*

Comment: I didn't notice that. Thanks and sorry!

Comment: If this is enough for you, I'll create an answer from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [library introduction page](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php) in the PHP documentation says:

> This is an interface to the mcrypt library, which supports a wide variety of block algorithms such as
>   DES, TripleDES, Blowfish (default), 3-WAY, SAFER-SK64, SAFER-SK128, TWOFISH, TEA, RC2 and GOST in
>   CBC, OFB, CFB and ECB cipher modes.

This looks like the library is designed to support the different modes of operations orthogonally to the block cipher selection, which seems like a good idea in general. Also, as you already found out, there are two functions `mcrypt_list_algorithms` and `mcrypt_list_modes` to access them independently

On the other hand, the home page of the underlying library [libmcrypt](http://mcrypt.sourceforge.net/) says:

> It should be remembered that not all modes will work with all block ciphers, either because of
>   implementation constraints or design constraints.

There is no indication which mode would or wouldn't work with which cipher, though - maybe this could be dependent on block size?

It looks like detailed answers can only be found in the sources of either libmcrypt or the PHP wrapper.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it seems that mcrypt is not developed a long time so the source code is the last resort but most likely the best one.